# Spring Data sorting on wrong Table

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I have an app running Spring Data + Hibernate and the following query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW com.foo.dto.OfertaBancoDto(y,(SELECT CASE a.id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM Banco b LEFT JOIN b.blackList a)) FROM Oferta y WHERE y.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM Oferta o WHERE o.status IN (?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL AND o.status = 1)",
        countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(y) FROM Oferta y WHERE y.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM Oferta o WHERE o.status IN (?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL AND o.status = 1)")
Page<OfertaBancoDto> randomSearch(Set<StatusOferta> filtroStatus, Pageable pageable);
```

Everytime I try to issue an orderby:

```
new PageRequest(0, 10, new Sort(Direction.ASC, "titulo"));
```

the result query is (b.titulo is the problem, since b represents the wrong table):

```
SELECT NEW com.foo.dto.OfertaBancoDto(y,(SELECT CASE a.id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM com.foo.entity.Banco b LEFT JOIN b.blackList a)) FROM com.foo.entity.Oferta y WHERE y.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM com.foo.entity.Oferta o WHERE o.status IN (?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL AND o.status = 1) order by b.titulo asc
```

The correct query should be:

```
SELECT NEW com.foo.dto.OfertaBancoDto(y,(SELECT CASE a.id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM com.foo.entity.Banco b LEFT JOIN b.blackList a)) FROM com.foo.entity.Oferta y WHERE y.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM com.foo.entity.Oferta o WHERE o.status IN (?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL AND o.status = 1) order by y.titulo asc
```

How can I specify the table the orderby should filter on?

Comment: Have you tried using `new Sort(Direction.ASC, "y.titulo")`?

Answer (score 0):

What is the signature of your Repository? It should look something like this:

```
public interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
....
}
```

I suspect you used Banco for T. So to fix this, you can try 2 options:

1) Move the method in to the Repository for Oferta

2) Move this method into Custom Repository (I think this is better) http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementation

Comment: My signature is the following: `public interface OfertaRepository extends EntityRepository<Oferta>` and  `public interface EntityRepository<T extends AbstractEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> {}`. Also, the method in question is withint Oferta Repository.

Comment: I couldn't understand what you meant by moving the method to a custom repository. I thought I was already using a custom repo (OfertaRepository).

Comment: Oh, for query on custom objects like your case, it is better to use custom repository. Please see section 1.3 of this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Answer (score 0):

i guess your pageable is like：

```
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(offset, limit,sort)
```

do not use the Sort change your pageable like :

```
// Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "id");
Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(offset, limit)
```

Use sql to achieve the order by function :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT NEW com.foo.dto.OfertaBancoDto(y,(SELECT CASE a.id WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END FROM Banco b LEFT JOIN b.blackList a)) FROM Oferta y WHERE y.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM Oferta o WHERE o.status IN (?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL AND o.status = 1) order by y.titulo asc ",
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(y) FROM Oferta y WHERE y.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT (o.id) FROM Oferta o WHERE o.status IN (?1) AND o.dataRemocao IS NULL AND o.status = 1)")
```

Page randomSearch(Set filtroStatus, Pageable pageable);